# set minimum counter value in cassandra counter table

Tags: cassandra, cql

In cassandra is there any way to define minimum value of a counter in counter column. Let say when counter values reaches 0 it should not go below this even if i do decrement operation.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't. Your counter is initialized with a value of 0, you can increment it, decrement it, and query its value. It is an integer between (-2^64 and 2^63 - 1). Sum / substraction will overflow when you hit the min / max values.

If you try to handle the logic in your application, it would be easy if you only have 1 application who write, but you probably have more than one. It would be doable if your applications are on the same system where they can use a lock, again I am guessing that's not the case, plus the performance would drop. In a distributed environment, you would need to be able to get a distributed lock, the performance would suffer.

If you *really* want to achieve this functionality with Cassandra, you can emulate it with the following strategy:

**1. Table definition**

```
CREATE TABLE test.counter (
    my_key tinyint,
    my_random uuid,
    my_operation int,
    my_non_key tinyint,
    PRIMARY KEY ((my_key), my_operation, my_random)
);
```

This table will be used to keep track of the increment / decrement operation you are running. A few notes:

- The partition key my_key will be always used with the same value: 0. It is used to collocate all the operations (incremente / decremente) in the same partition key.
- The my_random value must be a random value generated without any
  chance of collision. `uuid` can be used for that. Without this column, executing twice the same operation (such as increment by 10) will be only stored once. Each operation will have its own uuid.
- my_operation keeps track of the increment / decrement value you execute.
- my_non_key is a dummy column that we are going to use to query the write timestamp, as we cannot query it on the primary key columns. We will always set my_non_key to 0.

**2. Counter initialization**
You can initialize your counter, say to zero, with:

```
INSERT INTO test.counter  (my_key , my_random, my_operation, my_non_key ) VALUES
( 0, 419ec9cc-ef53-4767-942e-7f0bf9c63a9d, 0, 0);
```

**3. Counter increment**
Let's say you add some number, such as 10. You would do so by inserting with the same partition key `0`, a new random uuid, and a value of 10:

```
INSERT INTO test.counter  (my_key , my_random, my_operation, my_non_key) VALUES
( 0, d2c68d2a-9e40-486b-bb69-42a0c1d0c506, 10, 0);
```

**4. Counter decrement**
Let's say you substract 15 now:

```
INSERT INTO test.counter  (my_key , my_random, my_operation, my_non_key ) VALUES
( 0, e7a5c52c-e1af-408f-960e-e98c48504dac, -15, 0);
```

**5. Counter increment**
Let's say you add 1 now:

```
INSERT INTO test.counter  (my_key , my_random, my_operation, my_non_key ) VALUES
( 0, 980554e6-5918-4c8d-b935-dde74e02109b, 1, 0);
```

**6. Counter query**
Now, let's say you want to query your counter, you would need to run:

```
SELECT my_operation, writetime(my_non_key), my_random FROM test.counter WHERE my_key = 0;
```

which will return: 0; 10; -15; 1 with the timestamp at which it was written. Your application now has **all** the information to calculate the correct value, since it knows in which order the incremente / decremente operations occured. This is of course necessary when the counter is reaching zero towards negative values. In this case, your application should be able to calculate that the right value which is 1.

**6. Cleaning up**
At regular interval, or when you query the counter, you could combine values together and delete old one in a batch statement to ensure atomicity, for example:

```
BEGIN BATCH
DELETE FROM test.counter WHERE my_key = 0 AND my_operation = -5 and my_random = e7a5c52c-e1af-408f-960e-e98c48504dac;
DELETE FROM test.counter WHERE my_key = 0 AND my_operation = 0 and my_random = 419ec9cc-ef53-4767-942e-7f0bf9c63a9d;
DELETE FROM test.counter WHERE my_key = 0 AND my_operation = 10 and my_random = d2c68d2a-9e40-486b-bb69-42a0c1d0c506;
INSERT INTO test.counter  (my_key , my_random, my_operation, my_non_key ) VALUES (0, ca67df54-62c7-4d31-a79c-a0011439b486, 1, 0);
APPLY BATCH;
```

**Final notes**

- Performance-wise, this should be acceptable, as write are cheaps, and reads are done on a single partition.
- Cassandra is an eventual-consistent DB. This means that this counter is also eventualy consistent. If you need strong consistency, you will need to tune your read/write consistency correctly:
  https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.x/cassandra/dml/dmlConfigConsistency.html

Comment: Noteworthy: Insert statements are not allowed on counter tables in cassandra 3.x

Comment: He didnt used counter here

Comment: A so detailed answer couldn't be left not upvoted

Comment: Another answer not really what is demanded but you still have the possibility. When a read is done on the counter. If value is under 0 do a reset to 0 by adding x value under 0 and show user 0. Not the best but that's what i'm going for.